# scala only if condition without else (not even default)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

It may be simple question, but I am new to Scala and not able to find the proper solution

I am trying to create a JSON object from the Option values. Will check if the value is not empty then create the Json obj, if the value is None I don't want to create the json object. With out else, default else is Unit which will fail to create Json obj

```
Json.obj(if(position.nonEmpty) ("position" -> position.get),
         if(place.nonEmpty) ("place" -> place.get),
         if(country.nonEmpty) ("country" -> country.get))
```

Need to put the If condition so that the final json string to look like

{
"position": "M2",
"place": "place",
"country": "country"
}

Answer (score 0):

```
val obj = for {
  p <- position      
  o <- otherOption
  ...
} yield Json.obj(
  "position" -> p, 
  "other" -> o)
```

Will only yield a `Some` of Json Object if all options are defined. Otherwise `None`

Comment: Thanks for the response @Martin Ring. The values (position, place,...) are not in a list. Its case class parameters which are Option.

Answer (score 0):

Option is a monad and there are few convenient ways for using it.
First, if you want to extract value you should use map or flatMap and getOrElse methods:

```
val res = position.map(value => Json.obj("position" -> value)).getOrElse(null)
```

Another way is to keep Option of another type and use it latter:

```
val jsonOption = position.map(value => Json.obj("position" -> value))
```

After you can use it in for comprehension with another options or perform another mutations without extracting:

```
for (positionJson <- jsonOption; xJson <- xJsonOption) yield positionJson.toString + xJson.toString

jsonOption.map(_.toString).foreach(print(_))
```

And always try to avoid pattern matching on monads.